# Running scala in intellij with only sbt, pros and cons?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

im getting started using scala, and i've been struggling a little bit with the setup, since most guide were a bit outdated.

However, I just ran my first hello world, and things are working fine. At the moment i have not downloaded scala, only sbt- the build tool.
Im wondering why am i able to run my scala code, without having downloaded scala itself?
Should i install scala in the long run, or will having sbt in the manner I am now, be sufficient?

Comment: No problem  . . .. sbt does everything for you.

Comment: Do get the Scala plugin for IntelliJ as well. But then you are all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im wondering why am i able to run my scala code, without having downloaded scala itself?

sbt by default [automatically](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Configuring-Scala.html) resolves necessary Scala dependencies such as `scala-library`, `scala-compiler`, etc. without us having to explicitly specify them under `libraryDependencies`. Executing `show scalaInstance` should output directories of Scala dependencies, for example on my machine it outputs something like

```
/Users/mario_galic/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.2/scala-library-2.13.2.jar
/Users/mario_galic/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.13.2/scala-compiler-2.13.2.jar
/Users/mario_galic/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.13.2/scala-reflect-2.13.2.jar
/Users/mario_galic/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jline/jline/3.14.1/jline-3.14.1.jar
/Users/mario_galic/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.3.1/jna-5.3.1.jar
```

hence out-of-the-box if we execute `show Compile / libraryDependencies` then `scala-library` should already be listed

```
sbt:hello> show Compile / libraryDependencies
[info]  List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.2)
```

> Should i install scala in the long run

Note that system-wide installation of Scala is separate from sbt managed installations of Scala. Personally I do think it is useful to have system-wide installation as well. For example, sometimes I want to quickly spin up Scala REPL for experimentation without having to create a full project. [`dwijnand/scala-runners`](https://github.com/dwijnand/scala-runners) is a great way to run Scala outside sbt project. Say we want play with draft Scala features such as [Improve REPL result printing for String and Product [ci: last-only] #8885](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8885), then we simply execute

```
➜ scala --scala-pr 8885
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/get-coursier/apps/maven-metadata.xml
  No new update since 2020-07-12 21:39:52
Welcome to Scala 2.13.3-20200608-225728-521a32a (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_252).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> case class User(name: String, age: Int)
class User

scala> User("Picard", 70)
val res0: User = User(name = "Picard", age = 70)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! "show scalainstance" is that in code or in my cmd?

Comment: @s3j80 That is from within sbt shell.